# Creating an SQLite database from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sqlite, export

What would be a proper way to create an SQLite database (a .db file) by querying some database tables on Oracle server? I want the Oracle server to do it periodically running a script so that I can download the .db file and use directly on an Android app that I'm developing.